# AWS-Get all deployed Gateway APIs in node.js

Tags: aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway

I want to get all deployed Gateway APIs' endpoints under my account in a node.js  function. Any API from AWS js SDK can achieve this？

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just want API ids and related meta data - yes, you can do it per region:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/get-rest-apis.html

Comment: It is in CLI. Any js API to do this?